# PayPal preapproved payment testing - how to trigger failed payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm working on a crowdfunding project using preapproved payments through PayPal. I'd like to test what happens when the preapproved payments are collected, but payment then fails for the following reasons:

1. The PayPal account has insufficient funds.
2. The credit card attached to the PayPal account expired.

Is there any way to trigger these situations using Sandbox? Ideally, we'd like to do testing similar to on WePay where entering specified amounts triggers these events. https://www.wepay.com/developer/reference/testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this doc on [Testing Error Conditions with Negative Testing](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/).